# Canvas animation using png file

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I am trying to make a racing game using canvas, and a png file with transparent background for the car.

I have a problem when I hold down on one of the arrows. In the opposite way of the movement it appears like a white shadow the old position of the car.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var canvas;
            var ctx;
            var car = new Image();
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;


            function startUp(){
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                loadImages();
                startGameLoop();
            }


            function startGameLoop() {

                setInterval(function() {
                    drawScreen();
                    drawCar();
                }, 16);
                window.addEventListener('keydown', whatKey, true);

            }

            function drawScreen(){

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                ctx.fillStyle = '#aaaaaa';
                ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.fill();
            }

            function drawCar(){

                ctx.drawImage(car, x ,y, 200, 103);
            }

            function whatKey(evt) {

                switch (evt.keyCode) {

                    // Left arrow.
                    case 37: {
                        x -= 15;
                    }
                        break;

                    // Right arrow.
                    case 39:{
                        x += 15;
                    }
                        break;

                    // Down arrow
                    case 40:{
                        y += 15;
                    }
                        break;

                    // Up arrow
                    case 38: {
                        y -= 15;
                    }
                        break;
                }

            }

            function loadImages() {
                car.src = 'http://sammywasem.com/images/f3-top.png';
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startUp()">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1050" height="620">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The car move is in fact the right way.
Say you press the right key : the event is sent to the window, and trapped by your code : the car goes right. But the event is also handled by the whole window, where it is understood as : move the window to the right.
So what you see in the end, since the window move more than the car, is a move to the left of the car.

What you need to do is to prevent the key event from bubbling further once you handled it : it is done with

```
event.preventDefault();
```

and

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

look [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/) to see the specifications of [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) or [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) .

i've done a fiddle out of your code, and updated it :

http://jsbin.com/joboxuvu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was one of my problems. I tried my original code, the one posted above, on my leptop and it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome. You mean there's an issue left ? i couldn't see the white shadow you're describing in either Chrome or Firefox (mac OS).

Comment: The problem is on my pc, and I think you couldn't see it. When I hold down on one of the arrows, every time the loop is executed, the screen is cleared, the car is drawn on the new x or y, and a white shadow of the car is drawn on the old x or y. It happens in all important browsers. I don't know, it is from my video card settings?

Comment: It most likely comes from the motion blur of your lcd screen (the color settings of older image take some time to reach the new value). Example  : http://www.hardware.fr/medias/photos_news/00/18/IMG0018164.jpg  Depending on lcd's quality, this effect can be important or null.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the response time of my monitor on fastest, now is on normal and is working properly. Also for my loop what function should I use? I saw that is better to use requestAnimationFrame instead setTimeout or setInterval, or setInterval(function, 1); (Execute as fast as possible). Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok great ! For your question, if i may i will redirect you to my blog where i wrote a few things about a game loop : http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/thoughts-on-the-javascript-game-loop/